# Specific feature from rust program only works on windows

Tags: linux, bash, rust

This has been very confusing to me. This program compiles completely fine on both windows and linux with the requested features. However, the behavior on linux (With the feature enabled!) is the same as if the feature was disabled on windows. Now, I've skimmed through the code (I didn't write this myself) and from what I can tell, there's no special dependencies or any reason from the code why this wouldn't be working. Everything else with the program works perfectly fine! I will leave links for the file in which said feature is programmed in, and you can browse the rest of the repository if you like. I will also leave a paste with the script that is used to compile this along with another program we use as libraries. I don't expect anyone here to go through all of the code and tell me exactly what is wrong obviously, but if anyone could point me in the right direction at least or explain how something like this is even possible, I would love them.
https://github.com/Putnam3145/auxmos/blob/master/src/reaction/hooks.rs

```
#!/bin/bash

# REPO MAINTAINERS: KEEP CHANGES TO THIS IN SYNC WITH /tools/LinuxOneShot/SetupProgram/PreCompile.sh
# No ~mso
set -e
set -x

#load dep exports
#need to switch to game dir for Dockerfile weirdness
original_dir=$PWD
cd "$1"
sed -i '1s/^/#define PRELOAD_RSC 0\n/' ./code/_compile_options.dm
. dependencies.sh
cd "$original_dir"

#find out what we have (+e is important for this)
set +e
has_git="$(command -v git)"
has_cargo="$(command -v ~/.cargo/bin/cargo)"
has_sudo="$(command -v sudo)"
has_grep="$(command -v grep)"
has_youtubedl="$(command -v youtube-dl)"
has_pip3="$(command -v pip3)"
set -e

# install cargo if needed
if ! [ -x "$has_cargo" ]; then
    echo "Installing rust..."
    curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
    . ~/.profile
fi

# apt packages, libssl needed by rust-g but not included in TGS barebones install
if ! ( [ -x "$has_git" ] && [ -x "$has_grep" ] && [ -f "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so" ] ); then
    echo "Installing apt dependencies..."
    if ! [ -x "$has_sudo" ]; then
        dpkg --add-architecture i386
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y git libssl-dev:i386
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    else
        sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y git libssl-dev:i386
        sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    fi
fi
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install -y lib32z1 pkg-config libssl-dev:i386 libssl-dev libssl1.1:i386
# update rust-g
if [ ! -d "rust-g" ]; then
    echo "Cloning rust-g..."
    git clone https://github.com/tgstation/rust-g
    cd rust-g
    ~/.cargo/bin/rustup target add i686-unknown-linux-gnu
else
    echo "Fetching rust-g..."
    cd rust-g
    git fetch
    ~/.cargo/bin/rustup target add i686-unknown-linux-gnu
fi

echo "Deploying rust-g..."
git checkout "$RUST_G_VERSION"
env PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 ~/.cargo/bin/cargo build --release --target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu
mv -f target/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/release/librust_g.so "$1/librust_g.so"
cd ..

# Auxtools dependencies
apt-get install -y build-essential g++-multilib libc6-i386 libstdc++6:i386

# Update auxmos
if [ ! -d "auxmos" ]; then
    echo "Cloning auxmos..."
    git clone https://github.com/Putnam3145/auxmos
    cd auxmos
    ~/.cargo/bin/rustup target add i686-unknown-linux-gnu
else
    echo "Fetching auxmos..."
    cd auxmos
    git fetch
    ~/.cargo/bin/rustup target add i686-unknown-linux-gnu
fi

echo "Deploying auxmos..."
git checkout "$AUXMOS_VERSION"
env PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 ~/.cargo/bin/cargo rustc --target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu --release --features reaction_hooks,plasma_fire_hook,trit_fire_hook,fusion_hook,generic_fire_hook -- -C target-cpu=native
mv -f target/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/release/libauxmos.so "$1/libauxmos.so"
cd ..

# install or update youtube-dl when not present, or if it is present with pip3,
# which we assume was used to install it
if ! [ -x "$has_youtubedl" ]; then
    echo "Installing youtube-dl with pip3..."
    if ! [ -x "$has_sudo" ]; then
        apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
    else
        sudo apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
    fi
    pip3 install youtube-dl
elif [ -x "$has_pip3" ]; then
    echo "Ensuring youtube-dl is up-to-date with pip3..."
    pip3 install youtube-dl -U
fi

# compile tgui
echo "Compiling tgui..."
cd "$1"
chmod +x tools/bootstrap/node  # Workaround for https://github.com/tgstation/tgstation-server/issues/1167
env TG_BOOTSTRAP_CACHE="$original_dir" TG_BOOTSTRAP_NODE_LINUX=1 CBT_BUILD_MODE="TGS" tools/bootstrap/node tools/build/build.js
```

So, for some further explanation, this program is essentially an external library used by our game server which runs on the BYOND engine, this library essentially handles a computationally expensive task(managing the atmospheric simulations) by using hooks (I don't understand all of it completely, to be honest.) The specific feature we're looking for is for the program to correctly handle atmospheric reactions(Fire), what actually happens is that it doesn't handle them, so no fire ever happens. The behavior is identical to that if I didn't specify any --features for the program and used it on windows.

Comment: What feature is that? `the behavior on linux (With the feature enabled!) is the same as if the feature was disabled on windows.` What behavior? When it happens?

Comment: @KamilCuk I've added an addendum explaining further the program, and the feature that is not currently working.

Comment: Have you run the unit tests and reviewed the results on both Windows and Linux? Or, no unit tests exist... whelp! Let this serve as a perfect case where a good set of unit tests could have been useful =)